# Add work item field to only one board in a project in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

There are multiple development teams in an area of the organization that work closely together. Each has its own Azure DevOps board under the same Azure DevOps project. All boards inherit from the same Azure DevOps process.

One team would like to add a field to a work item type, but only show that field on their board. The field would not appear on the same work item type on the other teams' boards.

Is this possible? Microsoft has good documentation for Azure DevOps but I can't find anything that speaks to this, and I can't accomplish it myself in the UI. Thank you for any insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a new field to a work item type of some team project, this field will be available for all project teams.

Each team can customize the card view on each board (backlog or sprint): [Add fields to cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/customize-taskboard?view=azure-devops#add-fields-to-cards), [Customize fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/customize-boards?view=azure-devops&tabs=basic-process#customize-fields)

Additionally, you can use process rules to hide fields ([Hide or restrict modification of a field based on a user or group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops#hide-or-restrict-modification-of-a-field-based-on-a-user-or-group)) as [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10761889/matt) mentioned. You can find each team as a group `[Team Project]\Team Name` in the conditions section.

Comment: It might be worth adding on that while it is added to the work item for all items in that project, it might also be possible to just hide/restrict editing the fields based-on group membership.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops#hide-or-restrict-modification-of-a-field-based-on-a-user-or-group